# CORS Policy Issue in Cosmos DB Table

Tags: cors, azure-cosmosdb

I am unable to see the CORS option in the settings panel of Azure Cosmos DB Table. Please help me on it

[Azure Cosmos DB Table options Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJaoy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately CORS is only currently supported for Cosmos accounts created with the Core (SQL) API. It looks like yours was created with the Azure Table API and so CORS isn't available.

Comment: Thanks for that information MarkXA.
May I know, why is that option disabled. Because when I've seen documentation, Azure table is having CORS option.

And is there any chance that CORS can be added back again to Azure Table API in future?

Comment: Azure Storage Tables have CORS support, but the Cosmos emulation doesn't yet. There's a feedback item for it at https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/36274552-add-cors-support-for-table-api if you want to leave an upvote or comment.